# Directive rendered via UI-Grid cellTemplate rendering incorrectly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I am experiencing a strange issue in that my directive seems to be executing on stale row.entities, meaning it does not get the new values as you scroll down or modify the sort of the grid.  The initial ~20 rows render fine but past that the directives become disassociated with the rows.

See my very hacked together example [here](http://goo.gl/3tlXyG).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like during sort values of the expression you pass to directive change, but the expression itself stays the same.

You should change scope `&` expression binding to `=` value binding (and access the value with `scope.installs`, without function call), then you will be able to track the changes.

```
// ...
scope: {
  installs: '='
},
// ...
```

Then, to track the changes you can use `scope.$watch` and put your code inside.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch('installs', function(newValue) {
    // your code, you can use newValue as current installs value
    var installs = newValue;
    // ...
  });
}
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lBrLYjhK3xPkzGecgoZ2?p=preview).

Comment: whether you use expression binding or value binding you get the same behavior (in both examples - the watch of course still solves the issue).  I was under the impression that the link method executed in the same manner watch does.  Could you possibly explain how/why the link function is behaving in comparison to the watch?