# Angular UI Grid not updating directives in cells

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a ui grid that contains a directive, this directive has an isolated scope and changes it's template basing on some logic.

The problem is that, when sorting (and also when PAGING), the 'logic' of the directive seems to not be correctly "re-evaluated".

In the specific example, the rightmost column should only see some "11" while if you try to sort by id (or the other fields) you'll see some spurios '0' appearing.

this is the ui:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ng-style="gridStyle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the js:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ngRoute", "ui.grid"])

.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Max",
      other: "pippo",
      number: 1
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Adam",
      other: "pluto",
      number: 0
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "Betty",
      other: "paperino",
      number: 0
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: "Sara",
      other: "fava",
      number: 1
    }, {
      id: 5,
      name: "Favonio",
      other: "favona",
      number: 1
    }],
    columnDefs: [{
      field: "id",
      displayName: "ID"
    }, {
      field: "name",
      displayName: "Name"
    }, {
      field: "other",
      displayName: "Other"
    }, {
      field: "number",
      cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><mydir data="row.entity"></mydir></div>'
    }]
  };

}).directive("mydir", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: "=",
    },
    template: '<div><label ng-if="data.number==1">{{set}}</label></div>',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

      scope.set = -1;

      if (scope.data.number == 0) {
        scope.set = 00;
      } else {
        scope.set = 11;
      }

    }
  }
});
```

and here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/27yrut4n/

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it's a known bug:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4869

And I solved using watch like it's said here:

[Directive rendered via UI-Grid cellTemplate rendering incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321797/directive-rendered-via-ui-grid-celltemplate-rendering-incorrectly)